# Set the context root for Angular application to be deployed on Weblogic

Tags: angular, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy an Angular 8 application on a WebLogic 12c server. I built the application with 
    ng build --prod 
which generated files in dist folder. I then compressed all the files in dist into a WAR file that I deployed on Weblogic.

Weblogic set automatically the context root for the application. My problem is how can I change the context root of my Angular application.

E.g:

If my app name is **demo-angular**, Weblogic will set the context root to be **demo-angular**. The URL will then be **https://domain_name/demo-angular**.

How can I change this context root to **/__protected/demo-angular** so that the app url would be https://domain_name/__protected/demo-angular?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution.
To be able to set a context root for an application to be deployed on Weblogic,follow the below steps(Angular 8+ application):

1. create a **weblogic.xml** file in a new folder WEB-INF under ***src*** folder
2. Your weblogic.xml file should look like:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

   `<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.5/weblogic-web-app.xsd">`

       `<context-root>/__protected/demo-angular</context-root>`

       `<container-descriptor>`

           `<prefer-application-packages>`

               `<package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>`

           `</prefer-application-packages>`

       `</container-descriptor>`

   `</weblogic-web-app>`
3. Add in angular.json (build > assets section):

   `"assets": [
             "src/assets",
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/WEB-INF"
           ]`